# Different calulation using Javascript (add, substract, substract by perentage...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been searching around the web and SO for about a week now for a solution to (for me) a complex answer i believe. Note that JS and me are not really good friends.

I have a table with 4 cells that need calculation see code below:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="price1" name="price1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="quantity1" name="quantity1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="discount1" name="discount1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="total1" name="total1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Basicaly what i need is a dynamic solution that when i enter a price example 200 in the first input, the quantity 3, and disoucount 50 (in percentage) the last input should do the math, multiply 200x3 and susbtract the discount (IF discount) and put the result in input total1.

Not, my table AKA form, is used to make QUOTES for clients, i have a JS script that adds lines (that is why id's and name's have 1's in front, each line adds a number next to it.

Than the same script, should calculate a grand total, add all totals available and puting the result in an input called grandtotal. Example

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="price1" name="price1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="quantity1" name="quantity1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="discount1" name="discount1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="total1" name="total1"></td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="price2" name="price2"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="quantity2" name="quantity2"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="discount2" name="discount2"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="total2" name="total2"></td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="price3" name="price3"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="quantity3" name="quantity3"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="discount3" name="discount3"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="total3" name="total3"></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td>grand total</td>
  <td><select><option value="10">VAT 10%</option value="20é><option>VAT 20%</option></select>
  <td>VAT = (shows only the taxes of the amount)</td>
  <td>grand total = all totals + the vat</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Also, because this thing is complex i need a js script that will calculate on a select option, how much does the client needs to pay. If i select 20% a result will show in a `<p></p>` 20 percent of the grand total + vat.

I had found a table in JSfiddle from stackoverflow two days ago, but my computer crashed, and i ave been searching without any luck.

If someone could help by showing me a jsfiddle of a working code it will be muchly appreciated.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: There are 100's of posts here about calculators. Surely you found at lease some idea how they are done. At least provide an attempt otherwise it sounds like you expect someone to do all this for you

Comment: Have a look at knockout.js

Comment: Most of the ost with calculators do not work, i have tried them in jsfiddle manualy, most of them just don't run. I have tried my way, i block all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use classes for all the similar fields, instead of numbered IDs. Then you can use DOM traversal functions to find all the related inputs, and perform the calculation.

```js
$(".price, .quantity, .discount, #vat").change(function() {
  var row = $(this).closest("tr");
  var price = parseFloat($(".price", row).val());
  var quantity = parseInt($(".quantity", row).val(), 10);
  var discount = parseFloat($(".discount", row).val());
  if (price && quantity) {
    if (isNaN(discount)) {
        discount = 0;
    }
    var total = price * quantity * (1 - discount/100);
    $(".total", row).val(total.toFixed(2));
  } else {
    $(".total", row).val("");
  }
  var grand_total = 0;
  $(".total").each(function() {
    if (this.value != '') {
      grand_total += parseFloat(this.value);
    }
  });
  grand_total *= (1 + $("#vat").val()/100);
  $("#grand_total").val(grand_total.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><th>Price</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Discount%</th><th>Total</th></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="price" name="price1">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity1">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="discount" name="discount1">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="total" name="total1">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="price" name="price2">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity2">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="discount" name="discount2">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="total" name="total2">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="price" name="price3">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity3">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="discount" name="discount3">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="total" name="total3">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>grand total</td>
    <td>
      <select id="vat">
        <option value="10">VAT 10%</option>
        <option value="20">VAT 20%</option>
      </select>
      <td>VAT = (shows only the taxes of the amount)</td>
      <td>grand total = all totals + the vat</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="grand_total"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Barmar and thank you very much, i am very impressed by the code you made. It is exacly what i was searching for. I have 2 questions. Is it possible for you to show me only the VAT 20% ? where vat = shows only the VAT.

I am reading your code but this technic is new to me... i'm learning slowly i guess.

Also, i want on the side, to show the client how much advance he needs to pay so the quote is validate. kind of like the VAT `<select><option>30%</option><option>40%</option><option>50%</option></select>` i need next to it to show 40% (if 40% is select) of the grand total.

Comment: I think it's time for you to try to figure it out yourself. It's just grade school math.

Comment: Hello, ok i tried, and it is working, but please could you tell me if this is a good way or not (i don't need the best way of doing way, it just have to work, which it does) just need to know if its good or bad:

`var vatis = (grand_total / 100) * $("#vat").val();
    
    document.getElementById('vatis').value = vatis;`

Comment: If you're using jQuery, be consistent about it. `$("#vatis").val(vatis)`.

Comment: You should use `parseInt` and `parseFloat` when reading numbers out of input values, and you should use `toFixed()` when displaying the results so you don't get lots of extra decimals. See how I've used these in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, i was actually thinking about what was toDIxed and the parsINT parsFloat. Thanks again. You rock and roll!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments to the question. Any framework with 2-way data binding will help you focus more on logic than views. Here's the solution in AngularJS: http://jsbin.com/bilagisona/1/

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myCtrl", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.vat = 10;
    $scope.gt = 0;
    $scope.buffer = {
      name: null,
      price: 0,
      quantity: 0,
      discount: 0,
      total: 0
    };

    $scope.add = function() {
      $scope.items.push($scope.buffer);
      $scope.buffer = {
        name: null,
        price: null,
        quantity: null,
        discount: null,
        total: null
      };

      $scope.calculate_gt();
    };

    $scope.calculate = function() {
      var totalwithoutdiscount = $scope.buffer.price * $scope.buffer.quantity;
      $scope.buffer.total = totalwithoutdiscount - (totalwithoutdiscount * ($scope.buffer.discount / 100));
    };

    $scope.calculate_gt = function() {
      $scope.gt = 0;
      angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item) {
        $scope.gt += item.total;
      });

      $scope.gt += $scope.gt * $scope.vat / 100;
    };
  }
]);
```

```css
tr {
  background: #e3e3e3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js">
  </script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>
    JS Bin
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Name
          </td>
          <td>
            Price
          </td>
          <td>
            Quantity
          </td>
          <td>
            Discount
          </td>
          <td>
            Total
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="buffer.name">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" placeholder="Price" ng-model="buffer.price" ng-change="calculate()">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" placeholder="Quantity" ng-model="buffer.quantity" ng-change="calculate()">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" placeholder="Discount %" ng-model="buffer.discount" ng-change="calculate()">
          </td>
          <td>
            {{buffer.total}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button ng-click=add()>
      + Add
    </button>
    <hr>
    <h4>
        Entries
      </h4>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Name
          </td>
          <td>
            Price
          </td>
          <td>
            Quantity
          </td>
          <td>
            Discount
          </td>
          <td>
            Total
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
          <td>
            {{item.name}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{item.price}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{item.quantity}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{item.discount}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{item.total}}
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
    </table>
    <hr>VAT%:
    <input type=number placeholder="VAT" ng-model="vat" ng-change="calculate_gt()">
    </input>
    <h4>
      Total with VAT @{{vat}}%: {{gt}}
    </h4>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```